# WooCommerce JSON API get from category

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-json-api

I'm using woocommerce (which does not matter that much for my question) and I want to generate all products (posts) in a special category as JSON, and I only want some values from the product (post) and have some special names for the values. SO... What's best practice for generate custom JSON from WP posts?

One thought is to make a page and use a page as URL to the JSON, so therefore I'm thinking of making a template just for this and set `header('Content-Type: application/json');` and all that and just exclude the usual wp theming stuff, but I have the feeling that this can be done in a better way?

Comment: [here ya go](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/)...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I was just providing you with a plugin that will turn any archive, single, post, page, etc, into a json formatted object instead for quick API access. So for instance, if I wanted all of the products from the category of `animals`, it would look like, `http://mysite.tld/category/animals?json=1` and now all of those posts are presented to you in JSON format.

Comment: Sorry for missing your link. Deleted that comment. Yea, I've been playing around a little with this plugin, but how can I format the JSON as I wish? For example, "post_title" should be just "title" and stuff like that, and I also want some metadata and stuff for each post. That is, how do I customize the output if I use that plugin?

Comment: If you want to change the keys that are returned, or meta data, or modify the api in some way, go to that page I linked and cntrl +f `Introspector and data models`

Comment: Ah, nice. I do how ever experience som difficulties... It works for regular post categories, but not when i'm using woocommerse product categories? Then i just get null, no 404 or error. Is there a way for changing this without kill kittens and change the plugin core?

Comment: You need to set the custom post type for the query, because custom post types aren't included by default. =)

Comment: nah, i made it by using mysite.com/api/get_posts/?product_cat=the-categoryi-want&post_type=product :) thanks for your help. Now the only thing remaining is to get this babies as my own object.